# Remove menu and status line in FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to remove the status line at the bottom and the menu bar at the top-right corner.

Or, I want to just have the show status line check button in the menu and nothing else.

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: The default is to just have the 'show status line' in the view menu. I don't see any clean way to suppress these parts of the dialog. Like most Eclipse dialogs it is not designed for extensive customization.

Comment: How do I just show only the "show status line" item in the menu? Because by default it shows a bunch of other stuff like "Select working set" etc.

Comment: If your dialog is derived directly from `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog` there should only be the one item in this menu as I read the source. Other dialogs using `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog` add additional menu items.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I had derived it from `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog` which creates the additional menu items.
And my solution for removing all the items in the menu except the first one is risky and not the most correct way. :(
Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I found is to get all the menu items:

`menuManager.getItems();`

and then remove all the items except the first one which is the show status line action item.